# Problems with putting a saddle on a skeleton horse

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

I had a skeleton horse trap occur in my world and killed off the other skeletons and horses. I tried to tame the skeleton horse and once I get on it, it does respond to my controls but it seems super slow and unlike any other horse I've ridden in the game. I also can't open the "horse" inventory and equip a saddle. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Note: I'm using the free education edition since I'm still considering buying the game. (It's free with a school account)

Answer (score 1):

You can't put it on a skeleton horse in minecraft education edition. You can just start riding them without taming.

Answer (score 1):

1.The saddle on skeleton horse is Minecraft `Java-Edition` only

[image]

2. If your horse seems super slow, this is normal , unlike normal horses they have different speed (stats), skeleton horse have a fixed speed

if walking speed = 1 , running speed = 1.5 , skeleton horse speed = 2

Answer (score -1):

I heard some people say skeleton horses can't be equiped with armor or saddles. So I  don't think your doing anything wrong. But don't take my word for it, im not a "Minecraft Expert", I just play for fun...

Comment: Idk man. I've seen plenty of youtubers do it so it's definitely something I'm doing.

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: I have education edition 1.15.0

Comment: @SaiJeyaprakash most youtubers dont use Education Edition. Are you sure?

Comment: Yeah, it probably is just a me thing for using education edition. Anyway, I crossed the ocean and got myself a real horse, so it's all good.